# How to format text output in c

Tags: c, font-size, c99

How do i change the font size etc. In c99

Comment: C99 has no concept of fonts or for that matter any text output besides `printf()` (and its related functions).  You need to give us a lot more information about what system/libraries/frameworks you're using.

Comment: Font size is a function of your operating system. What system are you programming in?

Comment: How is this not a real question?

Comment: @NullUserException: From the description: "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."

Comment: Please clarify: Are you using Vim or Emacs?

Comment: @cHao He/she wants to change the font size on the output in C. That's a unambiguous, complete question to me.

Comment: Are you talking about the output from the printf function?

Comment: @NullUserException: Or maybe they're looking to change the font in their text editor.  As asked, it's not clear.  And *if* they're talking about the size of the output, it depends entirely on their platform, API, etc -- none of which has been specified.  No reasonable answer can be given that will be correct for everyone.

Answer (score 4):

C has no concept of font size. It will just output characters. If you want to control the look of those characters, that's outside the purview of the standard.

As an example, Windows provides DirectX functions that you can specify font types and sizes for. As does Windows [GDI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144819%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). I have no doubt that any GUI will give you that sort of control as well (Gnome, KDE et al) but it has nothing to do with ISO C other than the fact you'll be able to call them from your C code.